# no symbol named "VEXTEND" in "COMMON-LISP-USER"

Tags: common-lisp, packaging, sbcl

I am trying the examples of Anders' Inconvergent Lisp work at [Inconvergent Github](https://github.com/inconvergent/snek) 
While this has ran in the past, it doesn't now. SBCL version 1.3.1.debian

The reoccurring error for all the examples is:  no symbol named "VEXTEND" in "COMMON-LISP-USER"

I am uncertain how to proceed. Any comments or suggestions most welcome.

```
$ ./asemic.lisp asemic 
 ... 
; compiling (DEFPACKAGE :VEC ...)While evaluating the form starting at line 53, column 0
  of #P"/home/lisp/snek-master/src/load.lisp":
While evaluating the form starting at line 53, column 0
  of #P"/home/lisp/snek-master/examples/../src/load.lisp":
Unhandled LOAD-SYSTEM-DEFINITION-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {B3A3651}>: Error while trying to load definition for system snek from pathname /home/lisp/snek-master/src/load.lisp: no symbol named "VEXTEND" in "COMMON-LISP-USER"
```

Comment: See [various.lisp](https://github.com/inconvergent/snek/blob/d363ef07d669687b16d8f1c6465e0d9a454f5a18/src/various.lisp#L2)

Answer (score 2):

That project has a bit of “personal playground” character to it.  It seems that these utilities are defined in `pg-utils.lisp` and `various.lisp`, both of which lack an `in-package` form and assume that things then land in `cl-user`.  I'm not sure if this assumption is generally valid.  It would be cleaner to define a `snek/util` package and put these things there.

(Edited: removed first guess, add better suggestion.)

Comment: Thank you. Gives me something to go on. I do see it imports all from everywhere each time.

Comment: Looks like it is defined in [snek/src/various.lisp](https://github.com/inconvergent/snek/blob/d363ef07d669687b16d8f1c6465e0d9a454f5a18/src/various.lisp#L2)

Comment: Thanks, coredump, seems I overlooked it.